# Find an UTF-8 character, in an UTF-8 text file in python

Tags: python, text, utf-8

So, i want to find an UTF-8 type letter in my text file.

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open ('english_words.txt','r','utf-8')

#The TXT file contains these datas (english-hungarian words)

#artist-művész
#consume-használó
#adversary-ellenség
#nemesis-végzet
#beleaguer-bekerít, körülzár
#splash-sár, loccsanás
#defecate-megszúr, ürít
#stout-erős, vaskos


read = file.read()
print (read)
letter='e'
if letter in read:
    print ("It's TRUE")
else:
    print ("No, It's not working :(")
```

This statement's result is true. But if i change the statement to an "ű" or "ő" charachter, even if it is in the text,  it returns the "else" statement... so someone could help me, why it can't find those characters in the read text, please ?

Comment: 1- `use io.open()` instead of `codecs.open()` 2- use unicode `'e'` -> `u'e'` 3- take into account Unicode normalization and "user-perceived characters" (`\X` regex (from `regex` module) -- eXtended grapheme clusters).

Comment: You really want to go and read up about Unicode at this point. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html for starters.

Comment: do you use python3 or 2.7 ?

Comment: @maazza: almost certainly 2.7, given that they are using `codecs.open()` and using plain strings isn't working..